# Can running javascript from the console be considered as XSS?

Tags: xss, javascript

[image: Screenshot of browser with open console and XSS alert popup.]

I did it from the console. Is this a security issues?

Answer (score 8):

No, that's not a security issue. Your console only affects how the website looks/acts for you, not for anyone else, and only you can put things in your console. (If someone tricks you into putting something malicious in the console, that is an attack, called [Self-XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-XSS), but that's just a fancy name for a social engineering attack against the human, not any sort of vulnerability in the website or browser.)